# FMX TWebBrowser cannot visit one website, but another

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, firemonkey, tls1.2

Delphi Pro 11.1 on Windows 10 to build a Win64 app.

In a FMX project, I placed a `TWebBrowser`. A button triggers the following code:

```
Web.Navigate('https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/petal');
```

Then I will see the following error message:

[image: TLS error message]

Transcript:

> Cannot securely connect to this page
>
> This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website's owner.
>
> Your TLS security settings aren't set to the defaults, which could also be causing this error.
>
> Try this:
>
> - Go back to the last page
>
> [Change settings]

But it works for:

```
Web.Navigate('https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=petal');
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Or, is there some other webbrower component I can use in a multi-device project?

Comment: The TWebBrowser emulates Internet Explorer. There should be an option to change it to emulate edge in Delphi 11. I suggest you try and open that page in Internet Explorer and see if you get the same result.

Comment: @AdriaanBoshoff Yes, Indeed I found the solution.. I changed the setting of IE for TLS. Checked the "Use TLS 1.2" and make it work. But for a multi-device APP, what is the best solution? Do i have to code seperately based on platform? Not tried on iOS/Android yet.

Comment: The TWebBrowser should work on other platforms without issues as it emulates the platform browser.